# AccessViolationException on rootFrame.Navigate to MainPage

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, uwp, nuget

I'm writing a program for a hobby, and wanted to make use of the UniformGrid control from the Windows Toolkit, but couldn't in Visual Studio 2015 so I updated to Visual Studio 2019. After changing the target version to a newer version and installing the Toolkit, I got an error for multiple bound elements saying that DisconnectUnloadedObject(int) was not implemented, so I clicked to the error from the error list and added some blank methods so the error would go away. After doing this, I keep getting an AccessViolationException from the RootFrame trying to Navigate to MainPage.

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
        {
#if DEBUG
            if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                this.DebugSettings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;
            }
#endif
            Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

            // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
            // just ensure that the window is active
            if (rootFrame == null)
            {
                // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
                rootFrame = new Frame();

                rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

                if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
                {
                    //TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
                }

                // Place the frame in the current Window
                Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
            }

            if (e.PrelaunchActivated == false)
            {
                if (rootFrame.Content == null)
                {
                    // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
                    // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
                    // parameter
                    rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
                }
                // Ensure the current window is active
                Window.Current.Activate();
            }
        }
```

I didn't alter the code for the rootFrame, so I have no idea why it's doing this. Also, I want to go and undo the blank methods, but I have no idea where to undo them, as the files don't show up in the SolutionExplorer and searching the solution for "DisconnectUnloadedObject" doesn't turn anything up. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT 1: I've found that the DisconnectUnloadedObject methods were added to MapPage.g.cs; removing them produces the following error for obj8, obj62, obj64, obj65, obj67, obj69, and obj1

> 'MapPage.MapPage_obj8_Bindings' does not implement interface member 'MapPage.IMapPage_Bindings.DisconnectUnloadedObject(int)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been a while, but I think if you do a clean and build, the g.cs (auto generated) will auto-regenerate. If not, go and manually delete the file. You could alternatively try changing the xaml. That should set a dirty bit somewhere and make the file regenerate.

It has been a while, but I have experienced the g.cs file breaking occasionally when making changes to UWP applications during the app running (or some such other nonsense...)

Comment: Thanks! I have more issues on the code but I am no longer getting the issue regarding DisconnectUnloadedObject, which was the main issue to begin with